# Display Count of sales for employees

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-server, database, group-by

I have three tables. PersonalDetail, Employee and Orders. Personal details has data about names and stuff. Employee table has professional data. Orders have sales history.

Table PersonalDetail

```
personalID    FirstName    LastName
 1              test         test
 2              test         test
 3              test         test
 4              test         test
 5              test         test
```

Table Employee:

```
EmployeeID    personalID     hireDate     Status
001              1            test         test
002              2            test         test
003              3            test         test
004              4            test         test
005              5            test         test
and more data
```

Table Orders:

```
 OrderID   customerID   EmployeeID    ShipmentStatus 
  1            10           002            P             
  2            182          001            P
  3            22           005            P
  4            10           002            P
  5            89           003            P
  6            76           004            P
  7            99           001            P
  8            111          001            P
  9            123          002            P
 10            647          001            P
```

I want to get the end result as:

```
employeeID     FirstName,LastName   Count(sales to customers)
   001           test test                  4
   002           test test                  3
   003           test test                  1
   004           test test                  1
   005           test test                  1
```

So far, I have this:

```
SELECT e.employeeID, Concat (p.firstName,' ', p.lastName) AS Name, o.customerID
FROM Employee ((
INNER JOIN PersonalDetail ON e.personalID = p.personalID)
INNER JOIN Orders ON e.employeeID = o.employeeID)
ORDER BY employeeID;
```

This gives me the following result:

```
employeeID    Name            CustomerID
001           test test          182
001           test test          99
001           test test          111
001           test test          647
002           test test          10
002           test test          10
002           test test          123
003           test test          89
004           test test          76
005           test test          22
```

I know how to display employee name against each customer order but struggling with displaying the count of orders for a particular employee.

Comment: Hint:  `JOIN`.  `GROUP BY`.

Comment: Please select only one rdms

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can join and aggregate:

```
select
    e.EmployeeID,
    concat(e.FirstName, ',', e.LastName) employeeName,
    count(*) no_sales
from employees e
inner join sales s on s.EmployeeID = e.EmployeeID
group by e.EmployeeID, e.FirstName, e.LastName
order by no_sales desc
```

Answer (score 0):

To avoid error on 'order by' use the count itself:

```
select
        E.EmployeeID,
        concat(E.FirstName, ',', E.LastName) employeeName,
        count(S.*) no_sales
    from employees E
    inner join sales S  on S.EmployeeID = E.EmployeeID
    group by E.EmployeeID, E.FirstName, E.LastName
    order by count(S.*) desc
```